# JQuery IF statement not working when using .append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im using .append() to print the value of an input field to a span. The form is AJAX so multiple values are inputted into the form therefore I want to print these multiple inputs. This works well, apart from the below IF statement isn't switching the string value of 'names', any ideas?

```
$("input").bind("keydown", function(event) {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : (event.which ? event.which : event.charCode));
    if (keycode == 13) {
         var value = $(this).val();
        var names = '';
        if (names == '') {
            names = value;
        }
        else {
            names = value + ', ' + names '.';
        }
        $("span#name1").append(names);
        return false;
    } else  {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: is names html or just a plain string? You probably want to use html() and not append().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name == ''` is always true in your code, and that's because it's the initialization value of your variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (names == '')
```

Should be:

```
if (value == '')
```

That is my guess simply because you are setting `names = ''` in the preceding line so it will always be true.

Comment: But aren't I changing it's value to that of 'value' when I do 'names = value;' in the IF? Or does var have a fixed value?

Comment: You are, but you are then changing it back again just before the `if`.